# Smallest possible way to store six uints

Tags: c#, bit-shift

If I have the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 and I want to store some combination of them in the smallest manner possible, how would I do it?

For example, I might want to store 1, 4 and 5.   Or perhaps 2, 4, 5 and 6.  Or maybe even all six numbers.  I will always have at least one number that needs to be stored.  I think I may have seen this accomplished with bit shifting but I don't fully understand how it works.  For what it's worth, my ultimate goal here is to save the absolute maximum amount of space because  these values need to be stored on a hardware device which has an extremely small amount of storage space.

EDIT ----------------------------------------

Thanks everyone for all the great suggestions.  I just wanted to clarify that the implementation in my application doesn't necessarily need to be as small as possible just something that I understand and would make sense to another developer coming along behind me.  The most important thing is being able to represent these values in the smallest manner possible because I've ultimately got to build a byte array with several other values and write it all to a device which has very limited storage.  Thank each of you again for the excellent suggestions!

Comment: Do you have any information about the *relative frequency* with which the different combinations will be used in the future? If you have that information then you can sometimes store these 31 different values in *on average* less than 6 bits. The trick is to assign variable-length bit combinations different meanings such that the most commonly occurring combinations get the shortest possible representations.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  More often than not, I *suspect* that I'll need to store all six numbers but that's really just an uninformed guess on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Flags]
public enum UIntEnum : byte
{
    None = 0x0,
    One = 0x1,
    Two = 0x2,
    Three = 0x4,
    Four = 0x8,
    Five = 0x10,
    Six = 0x20
};

public static class UIntEnumExtensions
{
    public static Boolean ContainsOne(this UIntEnum enum)
    {
        // For .NET < 4.0
        // return ((enum & UIntEnum.One) == UIntEnum.One);
        // For .NET >= 4.0
        return enum.HasFlag(UIntEnum.One);
    }

    public static Boolean ContainsTwo(this UIntEnum enum)
    {
        // For .NET < 4.0
        // return ((enum & UIntEnum.Two) == UIntEnum.Two);
        // For .NET >= 4.0
        return enum.HasFlag(UIntEnum.Two);
    }

    // And so on...

    public static List<UInt32> GetComponents(this UIntEnum enum)
    {
        List<UInt32> values = new List<UInt32>();

        if (enum.ContainsOne())
            values.Add((UInt32)1);

        if (enum.ContainsTwo())
            values.Add((UInt32)2);

        // And so on...
    }
}
```

Then, for example:

```
UIntEnum enum = UIntEnum.Two | UIntEnum.Six;

if (enum.ContainsSix())
    Console.WriteLine("Enum contains Six!");

foreach (UInt32 value in enum.GetComponents())
    Console.WriteLine("Enum contains " + value.ToString() + "!");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
[Flags]
public enum NumberEnum : byte
{
    None = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 4,
    Four = 8,
    Five = 16,
    Six = 32
};

public string ExampleMethodWithNumberCombinationsAsAEnum(NumberEnum filterFlags = 0)
{
 if ((filterFlags & NumberEnum.One) == NumberEnum.One)
 {
    //Do something with one
 }

 if (((filterFlags & NumberEnum.One) == NumberEnum.One) && ((filterFlags & NumberEnum.Two) == NumberEnum.Two))
 {
    //Do something with one & two
 }
}
```

Comment: +1 If you change that to `public enum NumberEnum: byte`, it all fits into a single byte.

Comment: Also as of _.NET 4.0_ there is a `HasFlag()` extension method for all `enum` values.

You would use it like so: `if(filterFlags.HasFlag(NumberEnum.One)) { ... }` You can also check for multiple flags using the __bitwise OR__ `operator |`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very difficult to imagine that you could store this in an array of `bool`s. Now, consider, what is a bit? A bit can represent two states, just like a `bool`. Now, integers are made up of bits. The smallest one available to C# that I know of is `byte`. A `byte` has eight bits. You could use one of those bits for each of the numbers you have to store. Let's number the bits from least-significant to most significant. We could store the presence of 1 in bit 0, 2 in bit 1, 3 in bit 2, and so on. Now we have a representation for the data.

How do we pack the data? You mentioned bit shifts, and you'd be right. You will probably want to use bit shifts, but you'll probably also need to use a few other operations; in particular, `~` (NOT), `&` (AND), and `|` (OR).

All together, you'd have something like this:

```
byte flags = 0;

// Let's add 2.
flags |= 1 << (2 - 1);

// Is 2 in it?
if(flags & (1 << (2 - 1)) != 0) {
    // Yes.
}else{
    // No.
}

// Let's remove 2.
flags &= ~(1 << (2 - 1));
```

How does this work? If `1` (1 in bit position 0) represents `1` being present, we can left-shift it over the bit position times to get a 1 in just that bit position. ORing two bytes together will take the union of the sets; ANDing will take the intersection. `a & ~b` removes all bits set in `b` from `a`.

Comment: Thank you for that example!  It clarifies a lot for me re: shifting and the other operators!

Answer (score 1):

You've said that you need to save space but you didn't mention RAM. Here's an approach which would take a little bit more virtual memory but would let you write simpler code.

```
readonly Dictionary<int, int> _dictionary =
        Enumerable.Range(1, 6).ToDictionary(i => i, i => 1 << i - 1);

int GetFlags(params int[] ints)
{
    //Do checks on the dictionary, etc.
    return ints.Aggregate(0, (current, i) => current | _dictionary[i]);
}
```

Then, you can use the code through:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 4;
var c = 5;
var result = GetFlags(a, b, c);
```

Alternatively, the body of `GetFlags` can be rewritten in the following way:

```
var result = 0;
foreach (var i in ints)
    result |= _dictionary[i];
return result;
```

Comment: If you filled it at runtime, wouldn't that be using RAM?

Comment: @icktoofay Yeah. The author didn't say anything about his RAM, just about his storage.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misinterpreted your comment about that.

Comment: With that said, though, the source would be simpler, sure, but you're adding some non-trivial dependencies: `Dictionary` and `Aggregate`, for example. Those are unlikely to have tiny implementations.

Comment: @icktoofay Agreed. My original approach was the one using `Flags` on an enum, but since you all brought that up, I just wanted to offer something alternative. Besides the above code can be rewritten so that the dictionary becomes a 2xn matrix and the initialization can be written in a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for this unique and elegant solution!  I hate only being able to choose one answer especially when I've gotten several that are worthy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use six bits of a byte to store a combination, that means that you can store one and one third of a combination in each byte, or four combinations in three bytes:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|12345612|34561234|56123456|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

To turn an array of values into a 6-bit value:

```
public static int GetCombination(int[] combination) {
  int n = 0;
  foreach (int a in combination) {
    switch (a) {
      case 1: n |= 1;
      case 2: n |= 2;
      case 3: n |= 4;
      case 4: n |= 8;
      case 5: n |= 16;
      case 6: n |= 32;
    }
  }
  return n;
}
```

To combine four of those values into three bytes:

```
public static byte[] PackCombinations(int[] values) {
  byte[] result = new byte[3];
  result[0] = (byte)((values[0] << 2) | (values[1] >> 4));
  result[1] = (byte)((values[1] << 4) | (values[2] >> 2));
  result[2] = (byte)((values[2] << 6) | (values[3]));
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* C# can handle C++ STL stuff (no idea), see `std::bitset` - [one reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/).

Otherwise, yeah, just a hot bit would fit them all in a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for below storage algorithm. It will require a box of 6-bit only.

```
class StorageBox
    {
        bool[] box = new bool[] { false, false, false, false, false, false };

        public void Addtobox(int number)
        {
            if (number<7 && number >0)
                box[number - 1] = true;
        }

        public string WhatIsinBox()
        {
            string result = "";

            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                if (box[i])
                    result = result + (i+1).ToString() + ",";

            }
            return result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
        }

        public void ClearBox()
        {
            box = new bool[] { false, false, false, false, false, false };
        }
    }


    class ExecuteSample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var box = new StorageBox();

            box.Addtobox(5);
            box.Addtobox(3);
            box.Addtobox(4);

            Console.WriteLine(box.WhatIsinBox());

            Console.Read();
        }


    }
```